# How to move edge loops made with knife using only vertexes?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertex-groups

So the image below is what I am dealing with. I want to move the cuts I made on this mesh ("mouth area") by using vertexes. However, when I do so it moves the entire mesh with it. Even tho I only grab 1 vertex. Any thoughts on how to go about doing so? I need to manipulate that center knife cut you see by the cursor by using its vertex. However, when I try It deforms the whole mesh instead of just moving that corner in the direction I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to deactivate the *Proportional Editing* button?

[image]